# Cisco mac table via snmp problem

Tags: snmp, mac-address, cisco

I'm trying to get MAC address table from port number on Cisco switch using [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801576ff.shtml) manual.

For this i make

`snmpwalk .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1` to get the MAC address table;

`snmpwalk .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2` to get the bridge port number;

`snmpwalk .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2` to get the bridge port to ifIndex mapping.

But the problem I'm facing is the follows: i have more than one bridge port number for one MAC: i.e. the first snmp contains

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.0.14.94.0.119.122 = Hex-STRING: 00 0E 5E 00 77 7A 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.0.14.94.10.250.7 = Hex-STRING: 00 0E 5E 0A FA 07
```

while the second:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.0.14.94.0.119.122 = INTEGER: 6
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.2.0.14.94.10.250.7 = INTEGER: 6
```

so... which MAC should I use for bridge port number `6`?

ps: i'm not an admin, so sorry if the question is stupid, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Searching for these OIDs, this is the first page that came up, and it is relevant, so thanks for asking it. Also I do think this question has several correct answers (by Nemo and Benny), at least if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the "forwarding database" (FDB).  What you are seeing is which port a particular MAC address will be forwarded *to*.  If several systems are connected to that port -- e.g., because what you plugged in to the port was a switch itself -- then multiple MAC addresses will map to the same port in the FDB.

What are you actually trying to do?  And why do you think this is on-topic for StackOverflow? :-)

Comment: i'm trying to... i've posted it :) i thought about serverfault but it seems to be abandoned. thanks, i think i'm a bit closer to understanding

Comment: i can only +1 your answer, cause my question was bad and it cant have an acceptable answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for some network topology like stuff.
[Here](http://dpnm.postech.ac.kr/papers/ICOIN/09/TopologyDiscovery_November_18.pdf) are some very good algorithms  for doing the same.

It describes Spanning Tree Protocol and FDB processing while getting data from a switch or router.(Algorithm-3 and 4 in pdf).

I hope, it helps you.

Comment: i can only +1 your answer, cause my question was bad and it cant have an acceptable answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above, the correct answer is that you should use both MAC address since both MAC address appears from that particular interface (Mac address table entries have many to one relation).

However, the port number you have is just the bridge port number. You will have to translate it to the Interface name using dot1dBasePortIfIndex => ifName mapping.